# Are the "shock" double firings in The Apprentice pre-ordained?

Tags: production, the-apprentice-uk

Every now and again, in The Apprentice, Alan Sugar will shock us all with a double firing making for exciting TV, but my question is about whether this is a little contrived.

TV schedules are planned well in advance, AFAIK, and presumably the BBC have already worked out the number of episodes they need.

But of course, firing 2 people in a single episode unexpectedly shortens the overall number of episodes by 1.

So the question is, is Alan Sugar master of the firings (and the BBC just air whatever number of episodes they end up with) our do they plan, e.g. we will have X number of episodes so we need 2 double firings (or 1 triple firing) this year?

Comment: All "reality" TV is contrived. Nothing you see is actually real.

Comment: But remember that the penultimate round is the interview round, and all but two candidates are binned at the end of the interview process. So it really doesn't matter how many candidates remain at the start of that week.

Comment: @Bobulous - but don't they wait until they are down to a certain number of candidates before they do the interview round?

Comment: The only reality show I liked or really watched was "Average Joe" where the entire thing was staged, including all the participants except for one, and they kept making it a crappier and crappier "reality show" to see his reactions.

Comment: Reiterating Tim's comment - reality TV is neither non-fiction documentary, journalism nor anything other than for-profit entertainment. Production "sprays" the coordinated events and post-production spends TONS of time logging everything so that they can take the spray and fabricate a narrative with the sole purpose of keeping you watching, not "reporting the facts". E.g. unless you see the lips moving in sync with the dialogue, more than likely the sentence has been cobbled together from disparate recordings..

Comment: Maybe I was being a bit naive, as I had always thought of The Apprentice as more of a game show than so-called "reality TV" (e.g. as opposed, to Big Brother and the like) and so had to have some semblance of fair play involved...

Answer (score 3):

I don't have inside knowledge, but I strongly suspect the rules are:

- there are always 12 episodes
- interview week is always the week before the final
- Sugar is given pretty broad discretion to decide how many get fired each episode
- with the proviso that there must always be at least one. He says as much - "[after the task] at least one of you will be fired", every episode

Exceptions to things said in the comments:

"all but two candidates are binned at the end of the interview process" - no, [the 2012 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apprentice_(UK_series_eight)) had **four** people in the **final**, two teams of two.

*So far*, there have always been five people in interview week - hence the title of the additional programme "The Final Five", which gives more background to the five about-to-be-interviewees. But I reckon this one is highly flexible.

Oh, and to point out an incompletenesss in your question - we have had two *triple* firings, [in the 2010 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apprentice_(UK_series_ten)#Week_4:_Online_Video_Channel) and [in the 2017 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Apprentice_(UK_series_thirteen)#Week_8:_Doggy_Business). In both cases, Sugar phoned the house to let them know that no one was coming 
back.